# Separate array of hashes by nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Hash` value lik this:

```
 hs = {2012 => [7,nil,3], 2013 => [2, 6, nil, 8], 2014 => [9, 1, 2, 8]}
```

The keys are years. I want to collect values backwards until `nil` appears like this:

```
some_separate_method(hs)
{2013 => [8], 2014 => [9, 1, 2, 8]}
```

I thought this is not difficult to implement by using `reverse_each`, but I couldn't. How can I make a method like this?

### Edit

With AmitA's code I could make it.

```
new_hs = []
hs.reverse_each{|k,v| new_hs << [k,v]; break if v.include?(nil)}
new_hs = Hash[new_hs.sort]
```

Comment: why is 2012 not appearing in the example of your result? Also - if you have the array `[1, 2, nil, 3, 4]` would you like the result to look like `[3, 4]`, or `[4, 3]` ?

Comment: 2012 doesn't appears because that is the result I want. And I want to get `[3, 4]` in that case.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer. Let me know if the order of the elements in the returned hash matter to you. Right now it's the opposite of what you asked for, but I can change the answer to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
res = {}
hs.to_a.reverse.each do |k, arr| 
  res[k] = arr.split(nil).last
  break unless res[k].length == arr.length
end
```

Comment: oh, great! this is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know Rails, so I did a double-take when I saw `arr.split(nil)`. (I looked it up--very handy.). Good answer. btw, do you need `.length`?

Comment: Sure. You're right, you actually don't need `.length`. You can use `res[k] == arr`.

Comment: Although, `res[k] == arr` has to compare N elements in case the length is the same.

Answer (score 1):

A pure-Ruby solution:

```
hs.reverse_each.with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  h[k] = v.dup
  ndx = v.rindex(&:nil?)
  if ndx
    h[k] = h[k][ndx+1..-1]
    break h
  end
end
  #=> {2014=>[9, 1, 2, 8], 2013=>[8]}
```

`v.dup` is to avoid mutating`hs`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit long but I think it should help anyone who's new to ruby and has a similar problem.

```
def some_separate_method(hs)
  new_hash = {}
  hs.each do | key, value |
    new_arr = []
    value.reverse.each do | item |
      break if item.nil?
      new_arr.unshift(item)
    end
    new_hash[key] = new_arr
  end
  new_hash
end
#=> {2012=>[3], 2013=>[8], 2014=>[9, 1, 2, 8]}
```